# Suggestions to use code instead of pipe function %>% %*%

Tags: r, function

Can someone please recommend changes to my following code where I don't have to use the pipe function `%>%` or `%*%` so I can accomplish same results but without `%>%` `%*%` . Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

```
 V = cov(returns)
 mu = colMeans(returns)
 mu.prime = t(mu)
 V.inv = solve(V)
 one=rep(1, 30)
 one.prime = t(one)

 A=mu.primV.inv%*%one
 B=mu.prime%*%V.inv%*%mu
 C=one.prime%*%V.inv%*%one
 D=B%*%C-A^2

 #mvp
 min.return = A/C
 min.dv =1/C

 #EZp
 EZp <- runif(n = 99, min =min.return, max = 0.0075) %>% as.list()
 st.d.zi = sqrt(var(EZp))
 risk = lapply(EZp, function(EZp)(sqrt(C*(EZp^2)-(2*A*EZp-B))/D))
 EZp <- as.numeric(EZp)
 df <- cbind(EZp, risk) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Without `%>%`? Just nest your functions. Without `%*%`? Write your own `for` loops (and suffer the performance consequences of trying native-R versus a primitive R function). (Note that `%>%` is from the `magrittr` package; `%*%` is base R and present everywhere R is present. Everywhere. Operating without it is not far from asking how to operate without the assignment operators, `<-` and `=`; it can be done, but why would you think it's necessary and even smart?)

Comment: BTW: `cbind(...) %>% as.data.frame()` is equivalent to `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`, both of which are unnecessary and exposing yourself to unnecessary risk. What document/tutorial/class/howto suggests that is the best way to go? Just use `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: Have you read any of [the documentation for `%>%`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/magrittr/versions/1.5/topics/%25%3E%25)? It directly says *"`x %>% f` is equivalent to `f(x)`"*, which means if you have `f(x) %>% g()`, then you can use `g(f(x))`. Please read that doc and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I will try these suggestions and update.